# Pubnub user-level access control with History feature enabled

Tags: android, pubnub

Is it possible to use Pubnub Access Manager at the user level with History enabled? For my Android application, I'd like to restrict access to a channel to only certain users that are within 2 miles of a location (representing that channel's location). However, I'd like to keep the History feature turned on.

In the Pubnub API Reference, "History: To access historical messages you must grant full read access at either the subscribe_key or channel level. When a user has the appropriate permissions they can access any data stored. If they do not have access a 403 will be returned by PAM." And I know that the more general permissions trump the more specific ones (i.e. if you grant access at the subscribe_key or channel levels then this overrules permissions at the user-level).

So can you not use the History feature if you want user-level access control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub Access Manager - `subscribe` & `history` need the `read` permission

To call `history` on a channel, a user must have `read` permission. There is not a separate permission for `history` from `subscribe`. This `read` permission gives the the ability to invoke both `subscribe` and `history`.

And you are correct, if you grant `read` permission at the channel level (this means not including and auth-key in the grant), then anyone can call `subscribe` or `history` on that channel.

Granting `read` at the sub-key level (grant without a channel or an auth-key parameter) will give everyone the permission to call `subscribe` and `history` on *any channel*.

So you just need to grant `read` for the channel on the user's *auth-key* for them to get history - and they will be able to subscribe as well.

If you just want them to get history once and then not be able to subscribe, then:

1. just have the server call history on the user's behalf and pass the results back to the user based on a GET from the user to your server.

*- OR -*

2. Grant the user `read` to the channel for 1 minute `ttl` on the user's auth-key. This will give them enough time to call `history` with not very much time left to `subscribe`.

I would go with option 1 though if you do not wish to allow the user to subscribe at all.